# How to Create Compound Dataset on HDF5 C#

Tags: c#, types, dataset, hdf5

i need to write some data to a HDF5 file, i have a list of objects of the class "OPC_UA" inside a "BV" class, i want to create a dataset with the name of the BV and inside the dataset i want to have the list of the "OPC_UA" objects, tha OPC_UA Class have 3 attributes, a Long int ,one float value and a Datetime that i will convert to a timestamp, i can't seem to make it work, the Marshal.SizeOf() doesn't work with classes but i cant do it as a struct... Here is my code:

```
 public void CriaHDF5Customizado(PackingConfigFile pf)
    {
        H5FileId fileId = H5F.create("pmdfq.h5", H5F.CreateMode.ACC_TRUNC);

        H5GroupId infoGroupId = H5G.create(fileId, "informations");
        H5G.close(infoGroupId);
        H5GroupId datasetGroupId = H5G.create(fileId, "datasets");

        long[] dims = new long[1];


        foreach(BasicVariable bv in pf.basicVariableList.bvList)
        {
            OPC_UA aux = new OPC_UA();
            var xx = bv.bvData;
            int tamanho = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(OPC_UA));
            dims[0] = (long)bv.bvData.Count;
            // dims[1] = (long)4;
            H5DataSpaceId spaceId = H5S.create(H5S.H5SClass.SCALAR);
            H5DataTypeId dataTypeId = H5T.create(H5T.CreateClass.COMPOUND, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(OPC_UA)));

            H5T.insert(dataTypeId, "TimeStamp", 0, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_UINT));
            H5T.insert(dataTypeId, "Quality", Marshal.SizeOf(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_UINT), new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_UINT));
            H5T.insert(dataTypeId, "Value", 2* Marshal.SizeOf(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_UINT), new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT));

            H5DataSetId dataSetId = H5D.create(datasetGroupId, bv.bvTag, dataTypeId, spaceId);


            //H5D.write(dataSetId, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.STD_REF_OBJ), new H5Array<OPC_UA>(bv.bvData.ToArray()));
            H5D.writeScalar(dataSetId, dataTypeId, ref xx);
            H5D.close(dataSetId);
        }
        H5G.close(datasetGroupId);


        H5F.close(fileId);
    }
```

And this is the OPC UA Class

```
   public class OPC_UA
{
    public DateTime timeStamp { get; set;  }
    public string data { get; set; }
    public Int64 quality { get; set; }

    public OPC_UA(DateTime? ts = null ,string dt = "",Int64 qlt = -99)
    {
        if (!ts.HasValue)
        {
            timeStamp = DateTime.Now;
        }
        data = dt;
        quality = qlt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public DateTime timeStamp { get; set;  }
```

DateTime is not an atomic datatype. Convert it into long/Int64 ticks. Then you might be able to write it.

```
public DateTime timeStamp 
    {
        get { return new DateTime(StartTimeTicks); }
        set
        {
            StartTimeTicks = value.Ticks;
        }
    }
public long StartTimeTicks;
```

The constructor may also be hindering it.

The workaround would be making a structure. Note: Make the structure of fields or properties, depending upon (GetFields)fields or (GetProperties)properties you will to use in the reflection to read it.

```
 public structure OPC_UA
 {

    public string data;
    public Int64 quality ;
    public DateTime timeStamp 
    {
        get { return new DateTime(StartTimeTicks); }
        set
        {
            StartTimeTicks = value.Ticks;
        }
    }
    public long StartTimeTicks;
 }
```

[Hdf5DotnetTools](https://github.com/reyntjesr/Hdf5DotnetTools) is a working C# wrapper on [Hdf.PInvoke](https://github.com/HDFGroup/HDF.PInvoke). You can write a compound dataset by using a C# structure list.

If you have any difficulty in using the functions of either Hdf.PInvoke or Hdf5DotnetTools, you can use its UnitTest project.